# how to fix "500 internal server error" in response to ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress

i am trying to get data from table via ajax call. but i get response as "500 internal server error."

the script for ajax call is as following

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#btn_add_section").on("click", function( event ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'getsections',
            },
             dataType: 'json',
            success: function ( response ) {
                alert(response);
                debugger;
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

---

method to be called in functions.php is following

```
function getsections() {

$output = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_sections WHERE sec_status = 1";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
if(!empty($result)){
foreach($result as $row) {
array_push($output, array('sec_id'=>$row->sec_id, 'sec_title'=>$row->sec_title));
}
}

wp_send_json($output);
die;
}
```

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getsections', 'getsections' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getsections', 'getsections' );

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn’t mind trailing commas, whereas JSON does:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Try deleting the trailing comma from

jQuery.ajax({ url: '', type: 'post', data: { action: 'getsections', }

So it becomes

jQuery.ajax({ url: '', type: 'post', data: { action: 'getsections'}

It may be that the model state is not valid with this in so the server cannot process the request.

Comment: friend i have tried your suggestion but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

"die" is a function and should therefore be called with parenthesis `die();`